# SetGeoAnchor in SphinxQL

Tags: sql, geolocation, full-text-search, sphinx

I am trying to implement full text search where hits are returned based on user location. I managed to do it using API and now I want to do the same thing using SphinxQL (because I need to combine data from several Sphinx indexes):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Sphinx::Search;

my $sph = Sphinx::Search->new();
$sph->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$sph->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@geodist ASC');
$sph->SetGeoAnchor('lat', 'lng', 0.5894, -1.4724);
$sph->SetFilterFloatRange('@geodist', 0, 100000);
my $res = $sph->Query( "... SOME QUERY ..." );
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly can do multiple indexes in Query

```
my $res = $sph->Query( "... SOME QUERY ...", 'index1, index2');
```

---

Otherwise you just need to use the GEODIST function...

```
SELECT *,GEODIST(lat, lng, 0.5894, -1.4724) AS geodist FROM ... WHERE MATCH("... SOME QUERY ...") AND geodist < 100000 ORDER BY geodist ASC
```